# Windows application to record conference with laptop?

Tags: windows, video-recording

[This thread](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19697/roundtable-town-hall-live-discussion-platform) was about web-based solutions, but I'm looking for a free/affordable Windows application to record a conference with a laptop.

If need be, I can buy a USB microphone and USB webcam, in case using the internal devices isn't recommended. Besides, with an external microphone, I could put it right in front of the loudspeaker for near-perfect audio.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One of many options you may discover is a program called [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/). The information on the linked web site indicates that audio is recorded. It does not reference specifically recording web conferences, but I suspect there's a strong chance that it will.

A [free trial download](http://www.fraps.com/download.php) is available, should you consider to check out the program. Ideally, you'd have a sample web conference with which to test the program's features.

US$37 is not particularly expensive for a program of this nature, but that's an opinion.

Comment: Thank you. Besides Fraps, I found VLC and Debut.